# User Data Script to start a Spring Boot application on Amazon Linux ec2 boot

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I'm seeking some assistance particular to AWS and running scripts on an Amazon Linux ec2 instance boot. This is a custom AMI image but of the Amazon Linux machine, just with Java, Maven, Gradle installed.

The problem I'm currently having is that I want the ec2 instance that houses my Spring Boot application to automatically start a Tomcat server on port 8080 each boot/launch. Ideally this means that when I start the instance through AWS, the server is already running without me SSHing into the instance myself to run the commands. I believed that adding "User Data" to the instance settings would solve this but it seems that the script is not executing on launch. There are also no logs produced in the init.d file indicating that user data ever ran, or any files created when I piped the output to a txt file. I'd love some advice on how to approach this if anyone has had a similar experience.

The script I'm loading into my "User Data" is as text:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/java-service-tier
./gradlew clean build
java -jar build/libs/<myApp>.jar
```

where `<myApp>` is my app's jar file produced as a result of the build command.

My project uses a middle-layer Java service application in Spring Boot to interact with a MySQL database hosted on Amazon RDS. This is built with Gradle. There is then a web-tier layer that talks with the service layer to make its data requests and manipulates the front-end in Angular based off the service layer responses. The architecture setup is sound and not an issue, but I thought I'd give some background in case it was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using relative path and shell specific variables. Does the script expect certain environment variables set?

```
<full-path-to-home>/java-service-tier/gradlew clean build
java -jar <full-path>/build/libs/<myApp>.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the user data script to reflect those changes. Still doesn't execute on instance launch. The script expects JAVA_HOME to be set, but doesn't need to set it as I've already done so during an SSH session on the ec2 instance.

Comment: No. You have to export JAVA_HOME in the script. You got it wrong. None of your login session script will not be executed. Don't make any assumption. It is better to make the script self contained. Instead of launching the instance every time to test, fetch your userdata using `curl` or `ec2metadata` and test it in a shell with no variables set (restricted environment)

Comment: I got this working now by using #cloud-boothook at the top of my user data entry. My understanding of this is that it will make the user data execute each boot, as I desire. I'm assuming the issue was that stopping/starting the server did not constitute a "launch" and therefore never executed the script. In terms of setting the environment variables, this is good to know for future scripting. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I encountered the same issue, can you send me the full script of your user data please?@bang Thank you so much